# Name 'partition_pdf' is not defined

Tags: python, py-langchain

I do ai program take question from user and give him answer from pdf file with Azure OpenAI nltk and langchain. this problem is showing to me while i am runnig the programm => {name 'partition_pdf' is not defined. Did you mean: 'partition_xml'? }

i tried uninstall ustractured module , python , and pip and and install they again but the problem still showing to me

Answer (score 3):

Try to downgrade the unstructured

```
pip install unstructured==0.7.12
```

Comment: Getting below error on installing this version.        register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
      [end of output]
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.